# Timeout waiting for Processor response on PayPal Hosted Checkout Page goest always on error page url

Tags: paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm developing a cart on a website and I'm integrating it using the hosted checkout page Layout C with iframe within the website page, I have configured all urls so cancel, return and error url but when I try with the 411111.. and 12/15 credit card for test in test mode the website goest always on error page and in the post data I can see 104 error "Timeout waiting for Processor response"

I have followed step by step the guide I dont know how to solve it!

Answer (score 4):

The 41111... card is not supported at this time.
Please use any other Luhn-valid card number. I.e. http://www.darkcoding.net/credit-card-numbers/

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with PayFlow, and many of those test numbers listed in the documentation fail if you have Fraud detection turned on. Here is another site to generate test numbers: http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com